# Passing parameters to a query in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to pass many parameters to a query in Android.
What I am doing is the following:

```
String final QUERY = "SELECT TA.ID FROM TAB TA LEFT JOIN PROP P ON P.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN LOC L ON L.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN TIME T ON T.ID = TA.ID  WHERE (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) * (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) + (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?)  * (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?) <=COALESCE(VALUE,0)*COALESCE(VALUE,0)  AND ? BETWEEN  COALESCE(BEGIN,0) AND COALESCE(END, 123456)";
String[] args= {"" + val1, "" + val2, "" + val3, "" + val4, "" + val5, "" val6, "" + val7, "" + val8, "" + val9}
cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,args);
```

But it returns an empty cursor.
Any help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure but it may be a reason. I have never seen any query with **TABLE** before **table name**

instead of

```
SELECT TA.ID FROM TABLE TA.............
```

just use

```
SELECT TA.ID FROM TA..............
```

Another thing is you have **10 ?** in your query and you pass a string array of **9 elements** as selection arguments.

Comment: In this case wouldn't SQLiteException have been thrown?

Comment: @Alex only because of that confusion I prefixed my answer with "Well i am not sure"

Comment: Ah sorry I mistype. The correct query is the following:
String final QUERY = "SELECT TA.ID FROM TABLE TA LEFT JOIN PROP P ON P.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN LOC L ON L.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN TIME T ON T.ID = TA.ID  WHERE (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) * (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) + (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?)  * (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?) <=COALESCE(VALUE,0)*COALESCE(VALUE,0)  AND ? BETWEEN  COALESCE(BEGIN,0) AND COALESCE(END, 123456)";

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the empty cursor is a correct result? You may want to go to emulator console and do the same sql in there to make sure.

As they write in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html 
"Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell"

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.3.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
.... enter commands, then quit...
sqlite> .exit
```

Comment: I alreday did. The query is correct and the result is not empty. The problem is that I am not able to write the query in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Table Keyword from Query.

And you have total 10(?) in query object and in args you give arguments you have 9 parameters.

So give total 10 arguments.

Comment: The keyword table is removed from the query. The question is updated. Still not working.